# How should i provide the Gatway public key so the gateway can decrypt the generated token?

Tags: javascript, google-pay

I am trying to integrate with Google Pay, my question is about how should i provide the Gatway public key so the gateway can decrypt the generated token. authenticating process fails from gateway side with "INVALID_DATA" for the "fluidData.value".

Documentation says *"Google creates encrypted payment data using the gateway-specific key that is
supplied in the Wallet request and includes it in the Google API response."

What is "Wallet Request" and how to provide that through Google Pay JavaScript API ?! where below the parameters used:

```
const baseRequest = {
  apiVersion: 2,
  apiVersionMinor: 0
};

const allowedCardNetworks = ["MASTERCARD", "VISA"];

const allowedCardAuthMethods = ["PAN_ONLY", "CRYPTOGRAM_3DS"];

const tokenizationSpecification = {
  type: 'PAYMENT_GATEWAY',
  parameters: {
      'gateway': 'cybersource',
          'gatewayMerchantId': '*********'
   }
}
```

Comment: you don't have to fiddle with the "gateway public key". Could you share a code snippet showing how you call the cybersource APIs?

Comment: The payment token generated from Google Pay API shall be used as a REST based service input for fluidData -> value. Where this value does not seems to be accepted by Cybersource as the error of the authorization process is INVALID_DATA for fluidData.value. that is why i suspected that Cybersource was unable to decrypt it !! what else could it be.

Comment: Could you share your code on how you create the REST API call with the fluidData value?